# Read .xlsx file using File stream in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel

Hi My question is I want to read .xlsx file using Vb.net file stream is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly.  XLSX is actually a ZIP file in disguise.  XML files are inside. If you really need to do this:

Download DotNetZip from http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/

You can then extract the XML files.